# How to create disconnected line graph?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wpf-controls, silverlight-toolkit

I am working with Silverlight and WPF stock exchange application. I'm trying to create a graph like scattered line graph.

How can I draw this chart? Can it be done by Silverlight Toolkit graph? Or can any one suggest me any easy but nice looking charting library?

I have drawn the chart image in paint for your reference.
[image]

Comment: I tried telerik chart. But it’s getting difficult for me. I'm finding somthing easy one, so I can make my management happy. I have drawn the chart image in paint for your reference..Please have a look.

Comment: Is was suspecting that your graph would contain gaps like http://www.tableausoftware.com/sites/default/files/disconnected_line_graph.png but from your sample it looks like there's always two corresponding dots that are connected?

Comment: **always two corresponding dots that are connected** Yes you are right.

Comment: But how to do that...Any Idea?

Comment: I don't know what kind of chart that is but I wouldn't call it a disconnected line graph. Do you know its name?

Comment: This chart can be created using 5 `LineSeries`. But then there will be 5 items in the chart legend. And I'm not sure that everything will be good with performance. Anyway it is any easier than creating your own series.

Comment: I have managed to do this only in consecutive order, here is screenshot http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8047386/disconnected%20chart%20test.PNG. Give me an example of your data source (how does your collection of points look?) and probably I will change the chart as it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the above chart easily using [Visifire](http://www.visifire.com/). I have attached the following XAML code for the same.

```
<vc:Chart xmlns:vc="clr-namespace:Visifire.Charts;assembly=SLVisifire.Charts" Theme="Theme1" Width="500" Height="300">

            <vc:Chart.Series>
                <vc:DataSeries RenderAs="Line">
                    <vc:DataSeries.DataPoints>
                        <vc:DataPoint XValue="1" YValue="6"></vc:DataPoint>
                        <vc:DataPoint XValue="2" YValue="10"></vc:DataPoint>
                        <vc:DataPoint XValue="1.5" YValue="" ></vc:DataPoint>
                        <vc:DataPoint XValue="1.5" YValue="5" ></vc:DataPoint>
                        <vc:DataPoint XValue="3" YValue="3" ></vc:DataPoint>
                        <vc:DataPoint XValue="2.8" YValue="" ></vc:DataPoint>
                        <vc:DataPoint XValue="2.8" YValue="8" ></vc:DataPoint>
                        <vc:DataPoint XValue="3.5" YValue="12" ></vc:DataPoint>
                        <vc:DataPoint XValue="3.5" YValue="" ></vc:DataPoint>
                        <vc:DataPoint XValue="3.5" YValue="8" ></vc:DataPoint>
                        <vc:DataPoint XValue="4.2" YValue="12" ></vc:DataPoint>
                        <vc:DataPoint XValue="4" YValue="" ></vc:DataPoint>
                        <vc:DataPoint XValue="4" YValue="8" ></vc:DataPoint>
                        <vc:DataPoint XValue="5" YValue="6" ></vc:DataPoint>
                    </vc:DataSeries.DataPoints>
                </vc:DataSeries>
            </vc:Chart.Series>
        </vc:Chart>
```

As you can see, I have used single series here with broken lines.

Below is the image for the above chart XAML.

[image]

Comment: Vivek, this example is perfect for me. Exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the standard WPF/Silverlight drawing methods? Since your requirements are not too complex, you could just throw a canvas with some lines and rectangles:

```
private void AddEdge(Point from, Point to, int nodeWidth)
{
    Line line = new Line()
    {
        X1 = from.X,
        Y1 = from.Y,
        X2 = to.X,
        Y2 = to.Y,
        Stroke = Brushes.Black,
    };

    Rectangle nodeFrom = new Rectangle()
    {
        Height = nodeWidth,
        Width = nodeWidth,
        Fill = Brushes.Black,
    };
    Canvas.SetLeft(nodeFrom, from.X - nodeWidth / 2);
    Canvas.SetTop(nodeFrom, from.Y - nodeWidth / 2);

    Rectangle nodeTo = new Rectangle()
    {
        Height = nodeWidth,
        Width = nodeWidth,
        Fill = Brushes.Black,
    };
    Canvas.SetLeft(nodeTo, to.X - nodeWidth / 2);
    Canvas.SetTop(nodeTo, to.Y - nodeWidth / 2);

    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(line);
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(nodeFrom);
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(nodeTo);
}
```

Then you can add edges easily:

```
Point from = new Point(15, 15);
Point to = new Point(100, 200);

AddEdge(from, to, 8);
```

You can also customize the styles of the nodes and lines as you want by only changing the brushes.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Looks so simple and easy..I will try this. Thanks..

Comment: +1, Thanks for your example. But the example provided by Vivek is perfect for me.

Answer (score 2):

You want beautiful chart right? Then I Suggest you to look into Visifire. You can have a look to the following example from Visifire Chart Gallery.

http://visifire.com/silverlight_spline_charts_gallery.php

[image]